# Nginx reverse proxy 404 multiple apps

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm configuring nginx reverse proxy functionality. It's not working for apps as written below. I'll give you an example of `/hbase/`. When I enter url `/hbase/` in browser, I get 404 it redirects to `/master-status` ( hbase path) but when I manually edit `/hbase/master-status` in browser it works,

```
server {
    charset utf-8;
    listen 80;
   # Hbase Works perfectly using location / , not working      like below.
  location /hbase/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:16010;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }
```

Comment: What does "manually edit /hbase/master-status in browser" mean?   Type in that URL? Edit something in a web-app?  Use web-dav to edit that page?